# Why dot net core removes the underscore from table and property names?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, naming-conventions, scaffolding

I have used the entity framework in dot net core. The database tables contain the underscore in the table name and property names. When I scaffolded the model classes, the database tables with fields are scaffolded successfully but the underscore from the property name is removed. Could anyone please let me know why this happening and how to keep the model class's field name's as same as the database table's field name i.e. with an underscore?

Comment: Sounds like a convention like how property names in C# are conventionally [Pascal Case](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase)

Comment: @phuzi but I want the same property name with underscore as in my database table. But I don't know how it is possible.
help much appreciated..... thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried the UseDatabaseNames option?

Comment: hi @ErikEJ could you please send the exact scaffolding command.

Comment: Why not start by sharing yours?

Comment: Google is your friend: "EF Core Preserve Column Names" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934893/how-to-prevent-entity-framework-core-2-0-from-renaming-tables-and-columns-in-gen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Entity Framework Core 2.0 from Renaming Tables and Columns in Generated Classes (Database First)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934893/how-to-prevent-entity-framework-core-2-0-from-renaming-tables-and-columns-in-gen)

Comment: simply add --use-database-names to your scaffolding command

Comment: This is now fixed in latest EF.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951447/scaffold-dbcontext-is-not-generating-column-as-same-in-table